# How do I make a file writable from inside Vim

Tags: vim

I am frequently opening files that are readonly, I would like to know if there is a way to make them writable from inside Vim. I **do not** mean `:w!`, I need the file to be writeable after I close Vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that after changing the file attributes Vim will detect it and will try to reload the file and you will loose what you typed.

The best seems to create a function that redefines the `autocmd FileChangedShell` to do nothing when the attribute change is detected.

See [this example of setting file attributes without reloading a buffer](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_file_attributes_without_reloading_a_buffer) where an example is given for making all files executables.

This should do the trick for you

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a unix based machine you can always just use the unix command.

```
:!chmod 777 %
```

http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html

Otherwise on windows, you should look into the calcs command:
http://www.delawarepchelp.com/system/dos/calcs.htm

Comment: Unfortunately if I have already edited the file, vim will want to reload the original file from disk.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution elsewhere:

```
 :set readonly!
 :set modifiable
```

my situation was that vim was opening my file, which I chmod 777 from the commandline before opening, as readonly. Not sure if this helps you at all...

edit: forgot the second command. only the combination of the two worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use :! to execute shell commands. So you could change the user using `:!chown myusername filename` or change the access right using for example `:!chmod o+w filename`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if the file was writeable only by another user (and you are not owner, so can't chmod it) you might map this command:

```
:command SuWrite %!sudo tee %
```

Of course, sudo -u username for other users

Answer (score 0):

`!sudo chmod 777 %`

When it asks if you want to use the buffer, type "O" for ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SudoWrite` command from the [vim-eunuch plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch), which enables you to write to a file with sudo even if you forgot to open vim with sudo. It's a great way to eliminate that annoying behavior when you forget.